# selecting a column greater than a specified value

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct, average

This is my current code:

```
select distinct categoryid, min(weight), max(weight), round(avg(weight), 2) as AVG_WEIGHT
from inventorypart
where categoryid is not null
group by categoryid;
```

I need to select the categoryid that has the avg weight greater than 4.

i have tried the following with no sucess

```
where categoryid is not null and avg(weight) > 4
```

Comment: use a HAVING clause.... HAVING AVG(WEIGHT) > 4

Comment: Use the having clause as others have already said. Also it is very unlikely you need to use DISTINCT, because you are grouping on category ID. It may also adversely impact performance.

Comment: please try to use having clause.It will solve your problem.because with 'where' clause you can not use aggregate functions so you have to use "Having AVG(weight)>4"

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE keyword cannot be used with aggregate functions, as WHERE is applied before GROUP BY. Use HAVING instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoryid, MIN(weight), MAX(weight), ROUND(AVG(weight), 2) AS AVG_WEIGHT
FROM inventorypart
WHERE categoryid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY categoryid
HAVING AVG(weight) > 4
```